# How to visualize the integration drift in a plot?

Tags: python, imu

I'm trying to achieve the following image:
[image]

Where red is the ground truth circle (vehicle driving in a circle), and green is the Integration Drift (numerical errors that occur when integrating).

I started by plotting the circle and having difficulties plotting the integration drift with python.

Note: I'm trying to use scipy's integrate.cumtrapz instead of the multiplication in some places, but it doesn't help me.

**These are the places I think it should be added and work:**

```
psie = 0 + integrate.cumtrapz(psidote, t);                                #  rad

xA1id = R0 + integrate.cumtrapz(0 + integrate.cumtrapz(xAddot1e, t), t);            #  m
xA2id = 0 + integrate.cumtrapz(R0*omega0 + integrate.cumtrapz(xAddot2e, t), t);     #  m
```

I believe the only issue in the code is in the variables `xA1id` and `xA2id` and up to that point, everything looks good.

**Current result is:**
[image]

**The code I wrote is:**

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import integrate
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

R0=5
omega0= np.pi
dt=0.001
    
N=1

te=np.arange(0,np.dot(2,N),dt)
    
psie=np.dot(omega0,te)
    
xA1e=np.dot(R0,np.cos(psie))

xA2e=np.dot(R0,np.sin(psie))

# circle plot
plt.plot(xA1e, xA2e, color='green', label='x-axis')

plt.show()


#  Integration drift:



dt=0.01

    
N=100

t=np.arange(0,np.dot(2,N),dt)

#  (1)  Noise-free IMU "data":

psidote=np.dot(omega0,np.array([1]*len(t)))

a1e=np.dot((np.dot(- R0,omega0 ** 2)),np.array([1]*len(t)))
    
a2e=np.dot(0,a1e)


psie= t*psidote


xAddot1e=np.cos(psie)*a1e - np.sin(psie)*a2e

xAddot2e=np.sin(psie)*a1e +np.cos(psie)*a2e

xA1id=R0 + t* (t*xAddot1e)
xA2id= 0+t*((R0*omega0) + t* xAddot2e)


plt.plot(xA1id, xA2id, color='green', label='x-axis')
plt.show()
```

**The equations come from:**

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

```
psie= t*psidote


xAddot1e=np.cos(psie)*a1e - np.sin(psie)*a2e

xAddot2e=np.sin(psie)*a1e +np.cos(psie)*a2e

xA1id=np.concatenate(([5], R0 + integrate.cumtrapz(np.concatenate((np.array([0]), integrate.cumtrapz(xAddot1e, t)), axis=0), t)), axis=0)
xA2id= np.concatenate(([0, 0],integrate.cumtrapz(((R0 * omega0) + integrate.cumtrapz(xAddot2e, t)), t[:19999])), axis=0)
```

**Result:**
[image]